# Eclipse 2020-12 IDE Where are my build errors?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have some legacy Java code that uses 32-bit Java 6 JRE. Coworkers have it building and running in Eclipse Luna, but I can't seem to download that IDE (not being a member) so I'm trying to get it to build/run in the latest Eclipse IDE (2020-12).

I have the Compiler compliance level set to 1.6, I have the 1.6 JRE installed and selected for the project's Run Configuration.

When I build, a progress bar appears, gets to 41%, then disappears. I assume the build has failed at 41%, but I can't find any output from the build so I can't really tell. Did it fail? Where and why?

Window > Show View > Console opens a Console window but even if I force a Clean & Rebuild, the top line of the Console window reads "No consoles to display at this time."

I guess my first question is, where can I find the build output?!

Comment: FYI, you can still download Luna, no registration needed: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/luna/sr2/eclipse-ide-java-developers

Comment: You can also check with Error log in Eclipse views to see if a problem is reported. Else, attempt to build your code in console mode with `Maven` or `Ant`, depending what builds your project.

Comment: What does "build" mean here, exactly what are you doing?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Sure, but you should always use the latest version and Luna is not needed here since Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18) supports Java 1.6 and even older independent whether 32-bit or 64-bit. The JRE used to run Eclipse can be a different JRE than the JRE/JDK used to code and run the application you write in Eclipse (Eclipse even supports having multiple JREs/JDKs).

Comment: @howlger sure and I completely agree. I was just pointing out that no registration is needed to download older versions of Eclipse (for whatever reason one might want to). But thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes, it was meant as an addition of what you're saying. The questioner seems to be more familiar with other programming languages than Java, so perhaps there is another misunderstanding here by not knowing about the incremental Eclipse compiler which does not print to the _Console_ but lists problems in the _Problems_ view.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Have you tried that link? Click on Windows 32-bit, a window opens, then closes. I assumed it's a members only download, but maybe it's a broken link. In any case, I'll proceed with the latest Eclipse.

Comment: @greg-449 To build, I'm using Project > Clean (Build Automatically is checked) from the menu strip. Is this functionally different than an "Ant build?" I see build.xml so I assume it should be an Ant build.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan "You can also check with Error log in Eclipse views to see if a problem is reported" Thank you. It's not easy to find that window (Window > Show View > Other > General > Error Log) but it does have errors and I can start there.

Comment: @MikeZ I did, and it prompts me to download a zip. I tried again after your comment to be sure, still working.

Comment: Project > Clean just erases things like .class files and then runs the compilers and builders configured for the project configured in the 'Builders' page of the project properties. If you have Build Automatically set you don't need to do the clean at all. Normally this does not run anything that would output to the console. It may well be that the last part of the build is just running quickly.  The 'Problems' view shows any current errors.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan The Error Log window had the error I needed. rmic isn't supported in Java 15. Damn, that was well-buried. Downgrading to Java 14 has solved that problem. I'm still working on other build/launch issues, but this is progress. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My original problem is resolved, here's the summary.

The error that I needed to see and fix was being reported in the Error Log window.

Window > Show View > Other > General > Error Log opens that window.

Ultimately, the problem was the project uses rmic and it's been removed from Java 15. Downgrading from Java 15 to Java 14 in the IDE fixed my build errors.

Thank you, everyone.